# pull together a bunch of git repos with tags

Tags: git, tags, clone, release

I have a project which uses code from several different git repos (some developed by a vendor) which I'd like to pull together somehow. I was thinking of using git submodules, and pulling in each module that I need. That seems to work OK. 
At this point I'm thinking of using git tags, to mark a release of the platform. I'm thinking something along the lines of :-

```
cd myrepo-master
git submodule update --remote
```

Then tag all the modules individually.

```
git submodule foreach 'git tag v0.1'
git submodule foreach 'git push origin v0.1'
```

And the master module itself

```
git tag v0.1
git push origin v0.1
```

At this point I'm a bit stuck. I was thinking I'd git clone, and then git checkout just that tag... but I guess that's not how things work? (there doesn't seem to be a way to specify tag when using git clone)

Am I completely barking up the wrong tree? Is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT: To clarify, we're simply trying to make sure that all the code that goes into test environments at a particular point in time (call it a release? version?) also gets pushed out to higher environments, including prod with exactly the same code. But that code is coming from several different repos.

Comment: A tag in Git is just a pointer to a specific commit, whereas `git clone` refers to an entire _repository_ of many commits.  They aren't the same thing.

Comment: yes, but if I tag everything at a particular point in time, how can I pull / clone / checkout everything somewhere else so it matches that tag or commit?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to tag the main module, not the submodules. For example in the main module you do:

```
git tag v0.1
git push
```

Then somewhere else, maybe in your build environment:

```
git pull
git checkout v0.1
git submodule update
```

That will checkout each submodule at the commit as recorded by the main module's tagged commit.

If you are starting from scratch, instead of pulling, you would do:

```
git clone url-to-the-remote-repo
cd main-module
git submodule init
git checkout v0.1
git submodule update
```